# SSRS 2016 - How to calculate a percentage difference between two values in a group?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2016

I'm creating a report that shows the sales of item before a date range and after a date range.

The part I ran into trouble with is the percentage difference between the total sales on Date 1 and Date 2.

Items can have no sales for a certain week.
The user can select multiple item ID's in the item ID parameter.

I can update the question to post my SQL query if needed.

**What I've tried**

Since I put a group on item ID I thought the `First` and `Last` functions would work.

Here's my expression on the column PCT.

`=(Last(Fields!total_sales1.Value, "Date1")- First(Fields!total_sales1.Value, "Date1")) / First(Fields!total_sales1.Value, "Date1") * 100`

But when I run the report I get the following results.

[image]

I need an expression on PCT column that will give me a percentage difference for each item pairs.

Comment: i assume you are using SQL Server because of the ssrs-2016 tag? i've edited the question and remove it after because i noticed you had some expression which wasn't valid SQL code.

Comment: Ideally you should add the SQL code, example data and expected results.. see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: My apologies, I've edited the question to remove the SQL tag. The question I was asking is for help with an expression in SSRS-2016 to calculate a percentage difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your scope is incorrect. Check what the rowgroup is called where you group by item id (let's say the row group is called "yourItemRowGroupName").

Then change you expression to use that scope rather than "Date1".

In fact you may not need the scope at all as it should work within the scope that expression sits (in your case, within your ItemID group.).

So try

```
=(Last(Fields!total_sales1.Value)- First(Fields!total_sales1.Value)) / First(Fields!total_sales1.Value) * 100
```

Or..

```
=(Last(Fields!total_sales1.Value, "yourItemRowGroupName")- First(Fields!total_sales1.Value, "yourItemRowGroupName")) / First(Fields!total_sales1.Value, "yourItemRowGroupName") * 100
```

You may have to handle divide by zero but try this to start with before you add any more complications.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks so much for your help. The divide by zero error did come up but I used an IIF expression to handle it.